# Dynamic callback on a dynamic function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I want to call a callback function after a called a function that dynamically calls a function. I am either wording it wrong or it is complicated. I am not sure. But here is the relevant code.

```
confirm_delete(delete_resource,$resource_id, function(){

    if ($confirm_delete === 1) {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().prev().hide();
    } 
});
```

The following is what it looked like without the attempted callback

```
confirm_delete(delete_resource,$resource_id);
```

Comment: What does `confirm_delete` do?

Comment: Chances are `this` isn't what you expect. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are looking for something like this:

```js
function confirm_delete(delete_resource, $resource_id, cb) {
    var $confirm_delete = confirm('Are you sure');
    if ($confirm_delete) {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().prev().hide();
        // call callback fn
        cb();
    } 
}

confirm_delete(1, 1, function(){
  console.log('im callback fn');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```